# Intersect two SQL statement in Yii?

Tags: sql, yii, intersect

I want to apply an intersect operator on two SQL queries, but I couldn't find any Yii method for it in CDbCommand. Is there any?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no INTERSECT operator in Yiis CDbCommand. But you can use "pure" SQL to make queries.

Examples:

```
$sql = "first select INTERSECT second select"; 
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

You could also use CDbCommands for making single queries, just use `buildQuery()` on them. It will looks like:

```
$firstSql = 'define sql here';
$firstSql->where('your condition');

$secondSql = 'define sql here';
$secondql->where('your condition');

$sql = buildQuery($firstSql) . ' INTERSECT ' . buildQuery($secondSql);
$result = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql)->queryAll();
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: For the time being, I have done this only. But this is sort of hack.

Comment: It is normal practice to use pure sql in yii, still not all sql function are implemented.